# Detecting the presence of IDLE / How to tell if __file__ isn't set

Tags: python, python-idle

I had a script that needed the use of `__file__`, and so I learned that IDLE doesn't set this. Is there a way from my script that I can detect the presence of IDLE?

Comment: Couldn't you just check if `__file__` is set?

Comment: Yes, but I was interested in IDLE itself, too.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no special variables set by the interpreter to tell you this. PyWin, PyScripter, and IDLE all show identical version, copyright, etc. So, it seems like the way to identify IDLE is to check whether or not `__file__` is set.

Comment: Thanks @agf, interesting - and a useful code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if '__file__' not in globals():
    # __file__ is not set
```

if you want to do something special if `__file__` isn't set. Or,

```
try:
    __file__
except NameError:
    # __file__ is not set
    raise
```

if you want to do something then raise an error anyway, or

```
global __file__
__file__ = globals().get('__file__', 'your_default_here')
```

if you want to have a default.