# Python Print output at same place or position working on IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a spinning command line cursor using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor-using-python)
>   [python 3 IDLE progressbar/loadingbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563320/python-3-idle-progressbar-loadingbar)

I want to print the output as below:

```
Percentage: 10%
```

and only the percentage keeps changing to 20, 30, 40 so on in the same position. Overwriting 10%. I saw many of the posts on stackoverflow. But none of them work right in Python 3.

I tried using \r, \c and even \b but does not work from within `print() or sys.stdout()`

I am trying this using IDLE and running the program from Python Shell by pressing F5. The environment is Windows.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: do you want a solution for unix, windows, or both?

Comment: Windows solution will suffice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995733/how-to-create-a-spinning-command-line-cursor-using-python

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Na, it printed junk character like this \|/-\|/-\|/-\|

Comment: Not sure I understand what is different, I pasted that code and produced the desired results, windows 7

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, sys.stdout.write('\b') this line is actually producing wierd character on my terminal, not sure why. I can to paste a screen shot of the output. I dont know how paste the screen shot in stackoverflow either. But I am not getting the characters replaced as they get printed.

Comment: The IDLE console doesn't support using `\b` and `\r` to backtrack and overwrite characters that have been printed.  Such techniques will work if you run python.exe from a cmd.exe window.

Comment: @BrianL , feel like you are right. So what might be the solution...?

Comment: Either run your program from a cmd window, or put up with the fact that your output is going to be on several lines?  Or turn your program into a GUI program so that you actually have control over what is on the screen...

Comment: If there's a way for your program to tell whether it's running from within IDLE or not -- and there probably is -- just create two versions of you progress indicator and use the appropriate one. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049481/detecting-the-presence-of-idle-how-to-tell-if-file-isnt-set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDLE does not provide a true TTY/terminal.  Sorry.

Test your program by running it from the windows command line:

`C:\PythonXX\python.exe path\to\script.py`